# Error in getting Contract ID from Contract template

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to setup and activate contract while releasing invoice after creating Sales Order.

But everytime I try to release, I get this error.

[image]

The message reads as follows:

> Inserting 'Contract' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. Error: 'Contract ID' cannot be empty.

But before that I have made Contract template and a Customer Contract for the Customer as well which uses the Contract template.

Here is the code that is raising this error.

```
private Contract CreateActivateContract(ContractMaint contractMaint, DateTime? invoiceDate, int? customerID, int? customerLocationID, string simCardID, string phoneNumber, CTBillEngine engine)
    {
      contractMaint.Clear();
      //initialize new contract
      Contract contract = (Contract)contractMaint.Contracts.Cache.CreateInstance();
      contract = contractMaint.Contracts.Insert(contract);

      //look up contract template id
      Contract template = PXSelect<Contract,
                          Where<Contract.isTemplate, Equal<boolTrue>,
                          And<Contract.contractCD, Equal<Required<Contract.contractCD>>>>>
                          .Select(Base, "SIMCARD");
      if(template==null)
      {
         throw new PXException("The SIMCARD contract template was not found."); 
      }

      contract.TemplateID = template.ContractID;
      contract.CustomerID = customerID;
      contract = contractMaint.Contracts.Update(contract);
      contract.LocationID = customerLocationID;
      contract.StartDate = invoiceDate;
      contract.ActivationDate = invoiceDate;
      contract = contractMaint.Contracts.Update(contract);

      //store simcardid and phone number into the contract attributes
      foreach(CSAnswers attribute in contractMaint.Answers.Select())
      {
        switch(attribute.AttributeID)
        {
          case "SIMCARDID":
            attribute.Value = simCardID;
            contractMaint.Answers.Update(attribute);
            break;
          case "PHONENUM":
            attribute.Value = phoneNumber;
            contractMaint.Answers.Update(attribute);
            break;
        }
      }
      //save the generated contract
      contractMaint.Save.Press();
      //setup and actiave the contract
      engine.SetupAndActivate(contract.ContractID, contract.ActivationDate);
      return contract;

    }
```

Below is the screenshot from Contract Template and Customer Contract screens.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw1bo.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have auto-numbering disabled on the CONTRACT segmented key:
[image]

If that is the case, your 2 options are:

1. enable auto-numbering for the CONTRACT segmented key
2. modify the CreateActivateContract method to assign unique identifier to contract.ContactID:

   ```
   Contract contract =(Contract)contractMaint.Contracts.Cache.CreateInstance();
   contract.ContactID = "SOMEKEY";
   contract = contractMaint.Contracts.Insert(contract);
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I enabled auto-numbering for the CONTRACT segmented key.